# How to install a fuji xerox docuprint m255 z on ubuntu 12.04 - printer is on a windows network

Tags: printing

I have a number of desktop PCs running UBUNTU 12.04 on our Windows network. I have set up a Fuji Xerox Docuprint m255z with a fixed IP address. Is there a driver I can install for it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a driver here:
http://www.fujixeroxprinters.com.hk/en/Downloads.aspx?product=10417&category=5726&os=32768&dl=1

You can give that a try.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be existed anymore...